# Is there any way to have a thread for a view in MFC?

Tags: multithreading, view, mfc

I know MFC is not a popular subject here but I am looking for an advice for the platform anyway.

I have a multithreaded MFC application which is also using onIdle a lot and we want to add a plotting functionality, PGL in our case, to the application. Of course, once it added, the plot is flickering mainly because of the onIdle.

So I am thinking about having a thread for the view of plot. But not sure how to proceed. I believe I need to have ui thread for this since it should receive some messages. I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a couple of things mixed up here :

1. Using a separate thread for the graphics might be a good idea (it's hard to tell from your description), but may well be unnecessary. Unless your UI is becoming unresponsive or sluggish as a result of the plotting functions, there's unlikely to be any benefit.
2. If your problem is flickering, this is a completely different problem which is usually best solved by double-buffering the plotting - do the drawing to an memory device context, then when that's finished, copy that data (or preferably just the updated section of it) to screen.

Comment: As I said, flickering is due to OnIdle routine in App class. Stlll think thread for the view drawing is unnecessary?

Comment: Based on what you've put here and in response to the other answer, I'd say the separate thread is unnecessary and would add a lot of complexity without necessarily solving the flickering problem. It won't actually be UpdateAllViews that causes the flickering, it's the draw code in the views that it's updating that cause the flickering. It's a subtle difference, but an important one. If you double buffer the views then they'll never flicker no matter how frequently you update them.

Comment: +1 for point out that thread is not necessary. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Take all the stuff out of onIdle.  Stuff in onIdle = 'stop processing UI messages'.  Wots in there?

Comment: OnIdle stops messages processing only id one OnIdle run is long. OnIdle() gets executed only if the message queue is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't get rid of things from OnIdle as this real-time application does necessary things there. But I found UpdateAllViews is called in OnIdle and that's the cause of flickering.

Answer (score 0):

> The [MTMDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3wsyb55%28VS.80%29.aspx) sample illustrates an MFC user interface thread where user
>   interface events are processed in a separate thread from the main
>   application thread. This sample is a modified version of the
>   single-thread [MDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahd07sdd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) sample.